How to run a complex regression in R (for instance for frequency domain detrending)?
I am trying to detrend in a frequency domain.
Here is the paper that I am following:
Paper. Here is the paper which talks about detrending a frequency domain: Second-Paper.
My reprex:
library(quantmod)
getSymbols.FRED("GDPC1",env=.GlobalEnv)
# dim(GDPC1)
index(GDPC1) = as.yearqtr(index(GDPC1))
GDPC2 = ts(GDPC1,frequency = length(GDPC1))
time.trend = ts(1:310/310, frequency = 310)
N = 310
mytheta  = exp(-2i*pi/N)
W = outer(0:(N-1), 0:(N-1), function(i, j) mytheta^(i*j)) / sqrt(N)

lm( W %*% GDPC2 ~  W %*% time.trend)

which fails with

Error in model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
complex variables are not currently allowed in model matrices
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : imaginary parts discarded in coercion

How to run a regression with complex numbers in R?

A simple google search should yield an excellent answer by whuber at stats.stackexchange.com and also the complexlm package.

Dear Roland, Many thanks for your reply.

Is this the reply by whuber that you mention? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/analysis-with-complex-data-anything-different

library(complexlm); lm.fit(cbind(1, W %*% time.trend), W %*% GDPC2)

Dear Gabor, Thank you for reminding me the need for the intercept in the regression. I had forgotten that.
